# how to write on facebook wall in ASP .Net

Tags: asp.net

I want to post on facebook wall from my website, i had built the site in ASP .Net, I don't know how to perform this task. Can anyone please guide me or give me a script to post on facebook wall.

Comment: you want to post on user's wall?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a documentation on [Getting started with Facebook developers](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/)

The [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) is the core of Facebook Platform, enabling you to read and write data to Facebook. It provides a simple and consistent view of the social graph, uniformly representing objects (like people, photos, events, and pages) and the connections between them (friendships, likes, and photo tags).

Here's a [sample application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/164555/Building-a-Facebook-Graph-API-application-using-AS) from CodeProject to use the Graph API.

hope it helped !

Answer (score 0):

I've had some fun playing with the Facebook C# SDK for creating Facebook applications.

Are you using C# on your site?

The SDK is quite easy to get started with and there are a few tutorials etc...

[Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/)